# Problem with J2ME RecordStore update, delete operation

Tags: java-me, recordstore

I create a List showing data from a RecordStore. I tried to update a record and the re-display the list (re-open the same RecordStore), but the updated item doesn't change (still contain the old data).
I also tried to delete an item and the deleted item is still displayed in the list.
I run the program using emulator from NetBeans 7.0 with Java ME SDK 3.0

This is the code for updating the record

```
public void updateClient(Client cl) throws Exception{
        RecordStore rs=RecordStore.openRecordStore(String.valueOf(clientsStoreKey), true);
        int recNum=rs.getNumRecords();
        if (recNum>0){
            RecordEnumeration renum=rs.enumerateRecords(null, null,false);
            while(renum.hasNextElement()){
                int id = renum.nextRecordId();
                byte[] buff=rs.getRecord(id);
                Client temp=Client.createFrom(buff);
                if(temp.clientId.compareTo(cl.clientId)==0){  
                    temp.firstName=cl.firstName;
                    temp.lastName=cl.lastName;
                    temp.city=cl.city;
                    temp.state=cl.state;
                    temp.company=cl.company;
                    temp.phone=cl.phone;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(bos);
                    temp.writeTo(dos);
                    byte[] sData=bos.toByteArray();                  
                    rs.setRecord(id, sData, 0, sData.length);
                    dos.close();
                    bos.close();  
                    break;
                }
            }
            renum.destroy();
        }
        rs.closeRecordStore();       

    }
```

And this is the code to get the records

```
public Vector getClients()
    throws Exception{

        RecordStore rs=RecordStore.openRecordStore(String.valueOf(clientsStoreKey), true);
        int recNum=rs.getNumRecords();
        Vector cls=new Vector();

        if (recNum>0){
            RecordEnumeration renum=rs.enumerateRecords(null, null,false);
            while(renum.hasNextElement()){
                byte[] buff=renum.nextRecord();
                Client cl=Client.createFrom(buff);
                cls.addElement(cl);
            }
            renum.destroy();
        }
        rs.closeRecordStore();
        return cls;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting - your code dealing with record store looks rather OK to me. Is there a chance for some glitch in UI - like say using old or incorrectly updated screen object?

How do you debug your application? Since you mention *emulator*, `System.out/println` looks like a natural choice doesn't it? I'd use it to output content of the record right after setting it in `updateClient` and after getting it in `getClients`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I finally succeeded to solve this problem. Somehow, I try updating the record by delete the record, take the ID and then add the new one with the updated data.